# List subgroups in forest tree plot by metaprop

Tags: r

I have a simulated dataset like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  race_ehr = c("Patient race: Race1 EHR", "Patient race: Race1 EHR", "Patient race: Race1 EHR", "Patient race: Race1 EHR", "Patient race: Race1 EHR", "Patient race: Race1 EHR",
               "Patient race: Race2 EHR", "Patient race: Race2 EHR", "Patient race: Race2 EHR", "Patient race: Race2 EHR", "Patient race: Race2 EHR", "Patient race: Race2 EHR",
               "Patient race: Race3 EHR", "Patient race: Race3 EHR", "Patient race: Race3 EHR", "Patient race: Race3 EHR", "Patient race: Race3 EHR", "Patient race: Race3 EHR",
               "Patient race: Race4 EHR", "Patient race: Race4 EHR", "Patient race: Race4 EHR", "Patient race: Race4 EHR", "Patient race: Race4 EHR", "Patient race: Race4 EHR",
               "Patient race: Race5 EHR", "Patient race: Race5 EHR", "Patient race: Race5 EHR", "Patient race: Race5 EHR", "Patient race: Race5 EHR", "Patient race: Race5 EHR",
               "Patient race: Race6 EHR", "Patient race: Race6 EHR", "Patient race: Race6 EHR", "Patient race: Race6 EHR", "Patient race: Race6 EHR", "Patient race: Race6 EHR",
               "Patient race: Race7 EHR", "Patient race: Race7 EHR", "Patient race: Race7 EHR", "Patient race: Race7 EHR", "Patient race: Race7 EHR", "Patient race: Race7 EHR"),
  
  incentiveB = rep(c("Blinded Incentive (Derived) 1", "Blinded Incentive (Derived) 2"), times = 7),
  
  n = sample(1:100, 14),
  N = sample(101:200, 14),
  p_hat = runif(14, 0, 1),
  lower_ci = runif(14, 0, 0.5),
  upper_ci = runif(14, 0.5, 1),
  se = runif(14, 0, 0.1),
  output = paste0(round(runif(14, 30, 80), 2), "% [", round(runif(14, 10, 40), 2), " , ", round(runif(14, 60, 90), 2), "]")
)
```

Now, I can use the metaprop in R "subgroup=incentiveB" to facet the forest plot based on the value of incentiveB. The output by using the code below generated the plot with two forest plot: one is incentiveB=Blinded Incentive (Derived) 1, one incentiveB=Blinded Incentive (Derived) 2 under it.

```
myresult3 <- metaprop(n, N, data =df, studlab = paste(race_ehr), 
                      subgroup= df$incentiveB, method = "inverse", sm = "PRAW")


forest(myresult3, 
       fixed=F, 
       random=T, 
       pooled.events = T, 
       overall = T, prediction = T, 
       xlab = "Proportion of 'complete=1'", 
       smlab="p̂ [95%CI]", 
       leftlabs = c("Race", "n", "N"))
```

But instead of that, I want to create ONE plot with subgroup: Blinded Incentive (Derived) 1 and Blinded Incentive (Derived) 2 presented side by side and under each of them has n and N. May I ask how to update my code to make it possible? The ideal output should be like this picture which experimental and control correspond the Blinded Incentive (Derived) 1 and Blinded Incentive (Derived) 2 in my case,and mean and sd will be n N for each subgroup. Thanks~~!

[image]